# Substrings and Char.Is/Number Confusion.

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner at c# and how could I write a code that will check if:
the first 3 characters are letters
the next 3 are numbers, 
next two letters 
And  the last character a number. 
And if it is isn't write an error message.

I've tried using Substring(0,3) and putting it against Char.IsLetter just to attempt but failed.

Comment: When you say "letter" do you mean a Unicode letter? As `Char.IsLetter` checks?

Comment: Just to be clear you do mean a 9 character string.  And not a string that starts with 3 letter, 3 numbers, 2 letters and then any number of characters as long as the last character is a number.

Comment: If it is a 9 char string, then the very first test should be `value.Length == 9`. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a correct way to do it using `char.IsLetter` and `char.IsNumber`.

```
if(myString.Length == 9
    && char.IsLetter(myString[0])
    && char.IsLetter(myString[1])
    && char.IsLetter(myString[2])
    && char.IsNumber(myString[3])
    && char.IsNumber(myString[4])
    && char.IsNumber(myString[5])
    && char.IsLetter(myString[6])
    && char.IsLetter(myString[7])
    && char.IsNumber(myString[8]))
{
    // match.
}
```

Basically you have validate the length of the string, and then validate each character.

You could also use `char.IsDigit` to limit the match to radix-10 digit versus `char.IsNumber` that will match any Unicode character that is deemed a number (fractions, subscripts, superscripts, Roman numerals, currency numerators, encircled numbers, and script-specific digits).  Also `char.IsLetter` will also match any Unicode character that is deemed a letter which will stray outside of the basic A-Z.  To restrict numbers to 0-9 and letters to A-Z you could do this instead.

```
public static IsAtoZ(char c)
{
    return ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z');
}

if(myString.Length == 9
    && IsAtoZ(myString[0])
    && IsAtoZ(myString[1])
    && IsAtoZ(myString[2])
    && char.IsDigit(myString[3])
    && char.IsDigit(myString[4])
    && char.IsDigit(myString[5])
    && IsAtoZ(myString[6])
    && IsAtoZ(myString[7])
    && char.IsDigit(myString[8]))
{
    // match.
}
```

But honestly at this point a regular expression will be more terse.  But note that you'll still have to consider if you want to match Unicode characters and use the correct regular expression based on that.

Comment: @L.B What answer?  And I don't mean that any other answer is wrong, just that this is how you would do it using `char.IsLetter` and `char.IsNumber`.

Comment: Hey no worry ... I think @L.B just got up from bed :)

Comment: We don't know the string's length

Comment: @ivg That's why I'm checking it, because if the OP wants 3 letters, 3 digits, 2 letters and then a digit then they want a 9 character string.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a regex

```
bool isMatch= Regex.IsMatch("abc123de4", @"\p{L}{3}\d{3}\p{L}{2}\d");
```

Comment: This would also match "!!!!abc123de4$$$$" because there are no anchors.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{2}[0-9]{1}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matces = regex.Matches(input);
```

where `input` is the string you want to check.

When we pass the option `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to the constructor of the `Regex`, we say that it doesn't matter if the letters are capital or not.

You could avoid to specify this parameter and state explicitly that you want both capital and small letters, as Rahul has correctly pointed out in his comment. This is done like below:

```
var regex = new Regex("^[a-z][A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[a-z][A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}$");
var matces = regex.Matches(input);
```

Comment: @Rahul I am aware of this, but I thought that is more compact written in this way. Thanks for your comment, I will include it to my answer.

Comment: This wont really check if it is a Unicode letter though. If that was the intention by the op.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the individual characters of a string in C# like this:

```
string s = "1test";

char c = s[0];
```

c will be '1' one then.

In the next step you can use the Char.IsNumber Method which returns a bool. Just like this:

```
if(c.IsNumber()){}
```

Then you do the same thing for the next two chars except that you use the Char.IsLetter method.

Comment: Though I think regexes are probably a more elegant solution, this method is definitely easier for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Yes telling a beginner to use regex isn't a good idea.

Comment: @LasseKlüver: my thoughts exactly!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several elegant ways to do this. Since you said that you're a beginner to C#, I would suggest just finding the easiest (most pseudo-code-like, IMHO) way to just express the problem/solution:

```
private bool MatchesPattern(string test)
{
    // can't possibly match the pattern with less than 9 chars
    if (test.Length < 9) return false;


    int idx = 0;

    // test are letters
    for (int steps = 1; steps <= 3; steps++)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(test[idx++])) return false;
    }

    // test are numbers
    for (int steps = 1; steps <= 3; steps++)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(test[idx++])) return false;
    }

    // test are letters
    for (int steps = 1; steps <= 2; steps++)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(test[idx++])) return false;
    }

    // test last char is number
    if (!char.IsNumber(test.Last())) return false;

    return true;
}
```

You can test the results:

```
private void Test(string testValue)
{
    if (!MatchesPattern(testValue))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Better add a test that the string has a length of 9 or you could end up validating longer strings and getting exceptions for shorter ones.

Comment: I intentionally left that out (note the `.Last()`), LOL. Is this number pattern something I should have recognized? I just approached the problem exactly as stated, perhaps that was wrong?

Comment: The OP does say _And the last character a number_ but it seems likely that they meant the 9th character.  Even if that isn't what they meant you will still crash on strings with a length less than 8.

Comment: That's probably what we want though, right? If the length is less than 8, we *don't* want a false positive. A thrown exception is perfectly acceptable at this point. And since the OP mentions only that it's the **last char** and not the 9th char, for now, I'll keep my answer the way it is. Will definitely change if the specs change.

Comment: If it's less than 9 you could and probably should return `false`, how would that be a false positive?  Avoiding the exception here seems pretty obvious.

Comment: Where in the OP does it say 9 char is the max? You're making an assumption.

Comment: I didn't say it was the max, it's the min. 3+3+2+1=9.  It's simple math.  And even if they do mean last character instead of 9th obviously a 8 character string will not match since the 8th character has to be a letter and if that's the last character it's not a number, so at the bare minimum only strings with at least 9 characters will match.  Of course I think you should return 'false` for none matches where as you think an exception makes since if it's less than 8 characters.  I guess we'll just agree to disagree.

Comment: I guess where I disagree is the 3+3+2+1. I think it's clearly 3+3+2. And the 1 is the last char. If the OP clarifies it's 3+3+2+1, I'll make the change. I think you make a good point about bounds checking though. Will modify edit.